# Sacar el valor de un método en el modelo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Cardholder < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :type
  belongs_to :card

  def type
    account = type_account_id
    #raise "#{@account.inspect}"
    return account     
  end

  @value = type

  if @value == 2 or @value == 3
    validates :name, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Nombre'}
    validates :firstlast, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Apellido Paterno'}
    validates :secondlast, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Apellido Materno'}
    validates :age, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Edad'}
    validates :age, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :rfc, rfc_format: true
    validates :curp, curp_format: true
    validates :birthdate, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Fecha de Nacimiento'}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :mail, format: { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX , message: 'El formato del correo es invalido'}
    validates :telephone, length: { is: 8 , message: 'El teléfono debe tener 8 dígitos'}
    validates :telephone, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :mobile, presence: {is: 10 , message: 'El móvil debe tener 10 dígitos'}
    validates :mobile, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :street, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Calle'}
    validates :suburb, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Colonia'}
    validates :neighborhood, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Delegación'}
    validates :zip, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :state, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Estado'}
    validates :city, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Ciudad'}
    validates :country, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar País'}
    #validates :company_name, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Nombre de la Compañia'}
    validates :company_mail, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Correo de la Compañia'}
    validates :company_telephone, length: { is: 8 , message: 'El teléfonp debe tener 8 dígitos'}
    validates :company_telephone, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :company_street, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Calle de la Compañia'}
    validates :company_suburb, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Colonia de la Compañia'}
    validates :company_neighborhood, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Delegación de la Compañia'}
    validates :company_zip, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :company_state, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Estado de la Compañia'}
    validates :company_city, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Ciudad de la Compañia'}
    validates :company_country, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar País de la Compañia'}
    validates :job, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Puesto de Trabajo'}
    validates :bank, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Banco'}
    validates :clabe, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :status_id, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar estatus'}       
  else        
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :mail, format: { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX , message: 'El formato del correo es invalido'}
    validates :mobile, presence: {is: 10 , message: 'El móvil debe tener 10 dígitos'}
    validates :mobile, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
    validates :status_id, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar estatus'}
  end
end
```

Necesito obtener el valor de `type_account_id`; en el método `type` me da el valor, pero cuando lo quiero ocupar afuera en `@value = type` me envía nulo.

[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whhWi.png)

Este es el error que me da con los cambios echos de if pero al correr me dice que hay error antes de guardar no me esta validando nada por eso pasa al controlador de crear ahí me debería de mandar los mensajes que están en blanco y no hace nada de validaciones pasa directo como si no tuviera nada en el modelo

Comment: Bienvenido Fernando; el idioma oficial del sitio es **Español**, por favor traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario muy probablemente sea cerrrada.

Comment: yeah necesito sacar el valor de type_account_id para ocuparlo en el if pero afuera me lo manda nulo te lo agradeceria el @value lo manada nil

Comment: Es mejor que edites la pregunta (y título) directamente, aplicando la traducción. Sobre le problema: ¿qué es lo que buscas a través del `if`? No es muy claro ya que este está fuera de algún método. ¿Podrías detallar un poco más sobre el uso de ese código?

Comment: ya esta a ver si le entiendes mejor gracias lo que quiero es que @value tenga el valor del metodo type

Comment: Hola @FernandoMorales Utiliza el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/95257/edit) en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. Realiza el [tour] !

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que estás complicando de más el tipo de validación que buscas hacer a través de `@value`; sería más sencillo si, en lugar de utilizar `@value`, simplemente utilizaras el valor de `type_account_id` directamente pues, de acuerdo a tu código, `@value` siempre sería igual a `type_account_id`.

Por lo tanto, la condición podría simplemente ser:

```
type_account_id == 2 || type_account_id == 3
```

Además, no estás utilizando correctamente la condición en las validaciones, las cuales no aceptan un `if`/`else` directamente en el cuerpo de la clase, para ello *Rails* proporciona el método `with_options`, al cual puedes pasar un *bloque* que ejecute las validaciones que cumplan la condición.

Por último, me doy cuenta que todas las que están dentro del `else` también están en el `if`, por lo que son validaciones que **siempre** se deben ejecutar.

Considerando lo anterior tu modelo podría simplificarse considerablemente; por ejemplo:

```
class Cardholder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :card

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  # Validaciones que se ejecutarán siempre
  validates :mail, format: { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX , message: 'El formato del correo es invalido'}
  validates :mobile, presence: {is: 10 , message: 'El móvil debe tener 10 dígitos'}
  validates :mobile, numericality: { only_integer: true, message: 'El dato no es número'}
  validates :status_id, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar estatus'}

 # Validaciones que se ejecutarán únicamente cuando se cumpla la condición dada
  with_options if: :valid_type_account? do |type|
    type.validates :name, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Nombre'}
    type.validates :firstlast, presence: {:message => 'Falta Ingresar Apellido Paterno'}
    # ...
  end

  private
  def valid_type_account?
    [1, 2, 3].include?(type_account_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: el problema como dices tu si lo envio directo como if type_account_id == 2 || type_account_id == 3 me manda nulo type_account_id lo probare de la segunda forma que dices a ver si sale muchas gracias de todas formas

Comment: @FernandoMorales Utilizar `if type_account_id == 2 || type_account_id == 3` no funcionará debido a que está en el cuerpo de la clase directamente, razón por la que debes utilizar `with_options` (en el caso de las validaciones).

Comment: es que en mis validaciones dependiendo de lo que valga type_account_id me va a validar todo el formulario o si no que me valide solo esas a ver si me explico

Comment: @FernandoMorales Sí, creo entenderte, y justo eso es lo que refleja el código que propongo, en particular el segundo sería el más adecuado. ¿Cómo lo estás probando?, ¿te muestra algún error?

Comment: si me evia que no envio un argumento mira wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)        Para que me entiendas mejor type_account_id solo puede valer 1,2 o 3

Comment: @FernandoMorales ¿Podrías mostrar el error completo? Modifiqué el código para incluir también el valor `1`, pero fuera de eso te debería funcionar correctamente. Si muestras el error completo será más sencillo encontrar la solución.

Comment: @FernandoMorales Revisa nuevamente mi respuesta pues tenía un error en el método, pero ya lo he arreglado.

Comment: con tu cambio me manda que esta indefinido valid_type_account?

Comment: @FernandoMorales ¿Agregaste el método que se muestra al final del código? Después de `private` se define el método `valid_type_account?`.

Comment: Perdon no borre el otro jaja pero ya lo puse bien y me sale el mismo error de la imagen

Comment: @FernandoMorales Ese error hace referencia a un problema distinto, necesitaría ver tu controlador para poder saber que lo ocasiona.

Comment: Gracias por todo amigo @Gerry pero ya lo pude arreglar

Comment: @FernandoMorales Súper! Si la respuesta te ayudó no olvides aceptarla (dando clic en la paloma), si tu solución fue otra, inclúyela como respuesta (y acéptala). Suerte!